# Random Module Issue

Tags: python

I am starting off with Python Programming and was trying to work on a homework activity.

```
import random
Health = 50
Difficulty = 1
PotionHealth = random.randint(25,50)

CurrentHealth = Health + PotionHealth

print(CurrentHealth)
```

The answer that I am getting is 197. Shouldn't the max value of `CurrentHealth` be 100? Have got a lot of values more than 100. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are right, this code will never give you values above 100. There must be something else in your code that you're not showing us. We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unable to reproduce. What's the purpose of `Difficulty`? Is it a multiplier you are forgetting to mention perhaps?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, I restarted my Jupyter notebook and its working fine. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on my machine

```
import random

for i in range(100):
 Health = 50
 Difficulty = 1
 PotionHealth = random.randint(25,50)
 CurrentHealth = Health + PotionHealth
 print(CurrentHealth)
```

It produced this

> 77 85 91 100 100 80 86 87 93 83 81 88 92 83 89 87 99 89 91 81 83 84 96
>   75 75 97 84 77 92 76 91 83 85 80 80 96 96 76 91 79 95 94 99 93 75 89
>   93 77 100 83 79 95 79 84 96 75 100 77 90 94 99 88 88 93 89 91 100 99
>   97 89 95 95 99 76 93 84 79 79 91 96 77 75 85 93 97 84 92 88 75 100 97
>   99 77 95 93 80 77 88 100 99

there is no value more than 100.

In my opinion, you have to debug the random result (just print it) to see whether it produces correct values.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I restarted my Jupyter notebook and its working fine. Thanks